# dnsmasq blocks resolution of names of VPN servers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn, dnsmasq

I am running dnsmasq on Linux Mint 18.3 mainly to resolve a bunch of dev DNS names to localhost.

Recently I started using VPN connection and noticed that names of servers which are only available inside VPN network are not resolved:

```
ssh .... user@privateserver.network
ssh: Could not resolve hostname privateserver.network: Name or service not known
```

If I stop dnsmasq daemon it works as expected and privateserver.network is available and can be connected.

Any advice on how to approach this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the VPN startup/shutdown scripts to update the list of DNS servers dnsmasq uses to resolve requests.  There is a dnsmasq settting that will cause it to update its server list when the file changes.  You need to configure that as well, or trigger a reload of dnsmasq's configuration after the files changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the lead. I will try digging in this direction.